# I want to hide URL from window in java script

Tags: java, javascript

i wanted to hide URL from window . So no one can do inject the URL .

Thanks in Advance ...

Comment: This is not clear enough. Would you like to hide the current URL or target URL?

Comment: If the url gets used somehow (that's the point right?), anyone looking at the network pane from firebug or any browser debugger will be able to see it, whatever you manage to do to hide it.

Comment: What do you mean by "inject the URL"?  You can't prevent the user from seeing the requests their browser makes, or from making their own requests.

Comment: Possibly encoding the url parameters so they become unreadable is a better option?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove the url bar from a window using script inside a website. This would be a security issue.